# How to remove RETURNING clause in the Create method of gorm package?

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I got a little confused with the default behavior when creating a record for the [gorm](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html) package.

```
city := models.City

if err := databases.DBGORM.Set("gorm:insert_option", "RETURNING *").Create(&city).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

In logs I see such SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO "my_scheme"."city" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","name","country") VALUES ('2020-05-19 23:45:18','2020-05-19 23:45:18',NULL,'New York','USA') RETURNING * RETURNING "my_scheme"."city"."id"
```

As you can see from the query I have a double `RETURNING` clause which is not correct and raise an error.

Adding an `id` at the end of an SQL query seems to be the default behavior of the `Create` method. How can I change this behavior?

**models.go**:

```
package models

import (
    "my_app/proto"
    "time"
)

type City struct {
    Id uint64
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time
    proto.City
}

func (City) TableName() string {
    return "my_scheme.city"
}
```

Comment: I cannot change this default behavior of `Create` function, but the struct which you passed to the gorm function by address is going to be updated with the new ID and with created_at,updated_at fields.
Would you need anything else from the inserted row?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to change this behavior.

But if you want to get ID or timestamps (CreatedAt and UpdatedAt) after calling Create function, they will be automatically updated in your model passed by pointer.

If you have another field with a default value, add the `default` tag to this field in the model. And gorm will automatically update that field too after calling `Create`.

```golang
type City struct {
    Id        uint64
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
    DeletedAt *time.Time

    SomeField *string `gorm:"default:test"`
}

// ...

city := models.City{}

if err := databases.DBGORM.Create(&city).Error; err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", city)
```

```
[2021-04-13 21:39:44]  [1.06ms]  INSERT INTO "cities" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at") VALUES ('2021-04-13 21:39:44','2021-04-13 21:39:44',NULL) RETURNING "cities"."id"  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 

[2021-04-13 21:39:44]  [0.59ms]  SELECT "some_field" FROM "cities"  WHERE (id = 26)  
[1 rows affected or returned ] 

{
  "Id": 26,
  "CreatedAt": "2021-04-13T21:39:44.809605473+07:00",
  "UpdatedAt": "2021-04-13T21:39:44.809605473+07:00",
  "DeletedAt": null,
  "SomeField": "test"
}
```

If you don't want to update the model at all, pass it to the `Create` method by value, not a pointer, and ignore the `gorm.ErrUnaddressable` error.